# Is there any other way to avoid conflicting types other than using preprocessor directives?

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I have two different deployments in my project. For those two deployments, I have different structure members but with the same structure name. For example, I am using the below model to do-

```
#ifdef SATHISH
typedef struct{
       int id;
       char name[10];
}data;
#else
typedef struct{
       struct student s1;
       double average;
}data;
#endif
```

In this case when the `SATHISH` flag is enabled, the first structure will be evaluated; if the flag is not defined, the second structure will be evaluated.

Is there any other better alternative way to do the same thing without using preprocessor directives (like `#ifdef .... #endif` or `#ifndef .... #endif`)?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear what problem you are trying to solve. Obviously there's no way to do the *exact* same thing, but presumably you are looking for some *alternative*... it's just not clear for what.

Comment: Why don't you just stick with the 2nd structure definition and leave the unused fields empty ?

Comment: you want namespace in c?

Comment: @Coconop i am working on security related stuffs! i have two different deployment in my project! for those two thing the structure i am using is totally different. So i know this is one way i have suggested in my question. Is there any best alternative way is there?

Comment: @Sathish Why do you need alternative? Why preprocessor directives are not good enough?

Comment: @user694733 i know preprocessor directives are good enough. But for my knowledge i am looking for alternatives also!

Comment: There are two ways to ensure different program behavior: at compile time and at runtime! Your program uses the first way with preprocessor directives! If you want to do this at runtime, use `if` and other well-known C operations!

Comment: Don't do this. Having the preprocessor change a struct is almost a guarantee to get undebuggable errors in the future. You'll accidentally compile one file with the wrong define or you'll build with build artifacts from a previous build or something and you'll spend days trying to figure out why your code is overwriting random memory. Whatever problem you're trying to solve there must be a better way to do it (even though it's not clear what the problem is).

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of data types not grow, later, the compiled program, so you can define as much as data types as you want. Then, the syntax for `#if...` declarations would be more compact and readable:

```
typedef struct{
       int id;
       char name[10];
} data_version_1_t;

typedef struct{
       struct student s1;
       double average;
} data_version_2_t;

#ifdef SATHISH
   typedef data_version_1_t data;
#else
   typedef data_version_2_t data;
#endif
```

If you want a solution without preprocessor directives, perhaps you are looking for `unions`.
As you possible remember, a `union` is defined in the same way as a `struct`, but it works differently: its members are overlapped in memory (they share the same bytes in memory).

`unions` are mainly used with this purpose of safing memory space.

```
  typedef enum { version_1, version_2, } version_e;

  typedef struct {
       version_e v;
       union {
           struct{ int id; char name[10]; }  d1;
           struct{ int s1; double average; } d2;
       } u;
  } data;

  data person;
  person.v = version_1;
  if (person.v == version_1) {
       person.u.d1.id = 1234;
  }
  person.v = version_2;
  if (person.v == version_2) {
       person.u.d2.average = 12.34;
  }
```

If your compiler allows anonymous `structs` as members of `unions`, then the syntax can be more comfortable:

```
  typedef enum { version_1, version_2, } version_e;

  typedef struct {
       version_e v;
       union {
           struct{ int id; char name[10]; };               // Unnamed struct
           struct{ struct student s1; double average; };   // Unnamed struct
       } ; // Unnamed union
  } data;

  data person;
  person.v = version_1;
  if (person.v == version_1) {
       person.id = 1234;
  }
  person.v = version_2;
  if (person.v == version_2) {
       person.average = 12.34;
  }
```